# Model for probability threshold selection, how to make differentiable loss?

Tags: probability, calibration

I have an object detection model that outputs bounding boxes and probabilities associated with them. The probability expresses the chance that the object found is a tumor. I have noticed that the default 0.5 probability threshold works well for small objects but is heavily underestimated for small ones. I would like to create a model that would take the object volume as input and will give me a probability threshold as output.

I am not sure how to create such a model. One of the operations I need to perform is a comparison of the predicted threshold against the (constant) probabilities given by the detection model. This operation is not differentiable so I can't train this model with gradient methods. What would be the right approach to that problem?

Comment: Thresholds inherently lead to discontinuities and a subsequent lack of differentiability. It sounds like your real problem is with the object detection model and its inability to detect large objects and flag them as having a high probability of being an object. // Even if you were to come up with a way to model the threshold in terms of object size, you won't know the object size when you apply your model to new data, so I do not see how such a model would help.

Comment: I would like to use such a model as a postprocessing step. The model does detect both large and small objects. It outputs the bounding box coordinates and the probability associated with them being correct. We filter out boxes with small probabilities to avoid false positives. But the optimal threshold would be different for boxes of different sizes. That's why I want a model that would express this threshold as a function of bounding box volume.

Comment: In order to optimize what, the accuracy?

Comment: Yes in order to optimize accuracy

Comment: Accuracy is inherently discontinuous and, therefore, not differentiable.

Comment: Then log likelihood, would it work?

Comment: My recommendation is to say what you want to do and ask how to do it, rather than come up with an idea to accomplish what you want to do and ask about the idea, which may or may not be a reasonable way to approach your original problem. Do you know about [XY problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? They're extremely common in data science areas like machine learning, and this seems to be one.