# Finding a cut-off value

Tags: predictive-models

I am working on a computer program.  The program uses an open-source method to generate a score of how well details of a smaller image are found in a larger image.
I am trying to find a cut-off value that will indicate if the smaller image is contained in the larger image.  I suspect there will be different cut-off values for different images categories.  Pictures of chairs might have one cut-off value, while images of bone would have a different cut-off value.

I have been testing the program and have some test data.
The data:   1. Row number.  I.e., 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.
2. Do the images match - Yes or No
3. The numeric score returned by the program that indicates how well the smaller image is contained in the larger image.  A floating point number.

I would appreciate any help on how to proceed. I would like to generate a cut-off value from my data and then use statistically correct methods to show that my cut-off value is correct.
Thanks in advance for your help.
Jim

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Is [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/606020/247274) related?

Comment: There is simply no single correct way and no rules to guide you.  It will be a matter of opinion.  It will involve an arbitrary decision.  Some such decisions will be more or less defensible/appealing/intuitive to certain groups of people.  In fact, in many cases the instinct to create a cutoff comes out of the desire for simplicity or convenience rather than out of solid statistical or scientific reasons.  Statisticians spend a fair amount of time asking researchers what is their motivation in such cases and often showing that a cutoff will be of little use.

Comment: The question is about statistical criteria to use in dichotomizing.  "Computer program" merely indicates the content being statistically analyzed; it could just as easily have been stock prices or possum habitats.  The question must have been closed based on a misreading.